# Sending Firebase analytics to multiple Google analytics properties (GA4 and UA)

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I want to send Firebase project analytics to both GA4 and UA (GA-Universal) properties. Is that possible?

Does Firebase support integration with UA properties at all?